# MATLAB: Genetic algorithm - Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation

Tags: matlab, vectorization, genetic-algorithm

I have a GA with a vectorized fitness function, which works as expected:

```
objFunc = @(N) -fitfun(N, foo, NUM);

[ N, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~ ] = ga(objFunc, 3 * NUM, [], [], [], [], ...
                          [], [], [], options);
```

When bounds are introduced, it doesn't anymore:

```
UB = Inf(1, 3 * NUM);
LB = -UB;

for i = 3 : 3 : 3 * NUM
  LB(i) = 3000;
  UB(i) = 9000;
end

objFunc = @(N) -fitfun(N, foo, NUM);

[ N, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~ ] = ga(objFunc, 3 * NUM, [], [], [], [], ...
                          LB, UB, [], options);
```

Corresponding stack trace:

```
> Error using delaunayTriangulation/convexHull
  The triangulation is empty.
> Error in fitfun (line 66)
      [ facets, volume(i) ] = convexHull(DT);
> Error in run_fitfun>@(N)-fitfun(N,foo,NUM) (line 127)
    objFunc = @(N) -fitfun(N, foo, NUM);
> Error in createAnonymousFcn>@(x)fcn(x,FcnArgs{:}) (line 11)
  fcn_handle = @(x) fcn(x,FcnArgs{:});
> Error in makeState (line 64)
              Score = FitnessFcn(state.Population(initScoreProvided+1:end,:));
> Error in galincon (line 17)
  state = makeState(GenomeLength,FitnessFcn,Iterate,output.problemtype,options);
> Error in ga (line 359)
              [x,fval,exitFlag,output,population,scores] =
              galincon(FitnessFcn,nvars, ...
> Error in run_fitfun (line 140)
    [ N, ~, ~, ~, ~, ~ ] = ga(objFunc, 3 * NUM, [], [], [], [], ...
> Caused by:
      Failure in initial user-supplied fitness function evaluation. GA cannot
      continue.
```

To be clear, I have set `'MutationFcn', @mutationadaptfeasible`, and have also tried it with `'Vectorized', 'off'`.

**EDIT:**

As it turns out, I have `'PopInitRange', [ 5000; 7000 ]` set in the options, but the first (zeroeth?) generation of the GA shows that the incoming vector has LB (3000) set for every third variable, causing the `delaunayTriangulation` to be obviously empty.

```
N2 = reshape(N(i,:), 3, NUM).'

N2 =
   1.0e+03 *
   -0.0009   -0.0007    3.0000
    0.0007   -0.0002    3.0000
   -0.0005    0.0019    3.0000
    0.0002    0.0005    3.0000
    0.0021   -0.0009    3.0000
    0.0009    0.0015    3.0000
   -0.0007   -0.0005    3.0000
   -0.0008   -0.0013    3.0000
   -0.0004    0.0020    3.0000
   -0.0001    0.0003    3.0000
    0.0011    0.0010    3.0000
    0.0015    0.0010    3.0000
    0.0009    0.0013    3.0000
   -0.0008   -0.0010    3.0000
   -0.0005    0.0010    3.0000
   -0.0002    0.0020    3.0000
   -0.0003   -0.0001    3.0000
    0.0002    0.0015    3.0000
   -0.0008    0.0010    3.0000
   -0.0007    0.0017    3.0000
    0.0005    0.0018    3.0000
   -0.0002   -0.0003    3.0000
   -0.0006    0.0010    3.0000
   -0.0000    0.0008    3.0000
   -0.0006   -0.0012    3.0000
```

This seems like a case of the GA not respecting the initial population seeding range, even though it is clearly within the specified bounds. What could be a way around this?

Comment: You could edit your `fitfun` and disp the input `N` there. Then you can see what values cause the error. Maybe if you share them, we (I) can help you.

Comment: @JandeGier I have appended whatever relevant info I could find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess would be to set `CreationFcn` to for instance `@gacreationuniform`, but this does not work: the ga implementation still exhibits the default behavior and evaluates a vector of which the entries are equal to the lower bound values (if these lower bounds are finite).

A solution that does force a different first vector is providing this vector in the `InitialPopulation` field of the options. (Note: make sure that your inital vector does satisfy the bounds and constraints, otherwise, `ga` will still use his approach of evaluating the lower bound)

I hope that solves your problem.

By the way, you could include a constraint that checks if the triangulation will work (use a `nonlcon` constraint function for that).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm having to do exactly this as of now because even explicitly populating the entire `InitPopRange` vector with valid bounds doesn't seem to satisfy the solver.
Is there a way by which the fitness function can identify which generation number is currently being processed? Something like a state structure that can be accessed?

Comment: You can include a persistent variable in that function, that counts  the number of calls. Like this: `persistent counter`, `if isempty(counter), counter = 1; else counter = counter + 1; end`. You can also pass the `options` structure to derive the generation number I guess, but than you have to set generation values etcetera for that first in the options struct. (`clear all` deletes the persistent variables and hence resets the counter.)